# Textmate - keyboard shortcut for escaping quotes

Tags: javascript, escaping, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate, quotes

Is there a keyboard shortcut (or bundle) available that will escape quotes in Textmate? (specifically javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Source bundle that comes with Texmate does this.

Bundles → Source → Insert Escaped → Quotes

Comment: I was hoping to highlight a few lines of HTML code, and then use a shortcut to add in all the escapes. That's not possible? Otherwise, then this might be the best solution - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to escape javascript to make a bookmarklet, I've just found Bundles -> Javascript -> Copy as Bookmarklet to Clipboard (it also updates the written file to include the escaped version.